# How does Redux's Connect function figure out where my state is?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux

I would be really curious that how does the connect function figure out where my state is residing? Does it have any connection with the combineReducer's function? Is it getting the returned values from it?

Comment: Have you looked at the Redux source code?

Comment: sure thing, it did not get me closer to my problem, since the source code is not very self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

React-Redux's `connect()` function relies on the `<Provider>` component to put a Redux store into React's `context` feature so it can be accessed by any component nested inside the `<Provider>`.

I recommend reading the post [Build Yourself a Redux](https://zapier.com/engineering/how-to-build-redux), which covers many aspects of how Redux works, including `<Provider>` and `connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

In React components can intarect  using `props` or `context`.
You can  treat context as  kind of global  props - once context was defined in a provider class,  it could be accessed anywhere down tree. [More on context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

That what  react-redux do: it gives you `<Provider>` component, that requires to have store to be passed to explicitly.

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App ... />
  </Provider>,
```

It is responsible for creating context and setting reference to redux store to it.

On other hand `connect` function is [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). It wraps your component and  gives it access to provider's context. You can easily  use store without  using `connect` like this:

```
static contextTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object,
};

render() {
  const { store } = this.context;
  console.log(store);
```

to summarize:

[image]